Python: scraping links from multiple urls
I'm trying to adapt the following code to scrape links from various pages. For example, if each page has 40 links and I'm scraping 10 pages, then I expect to get 400 links total.
The web pages follow this pattern:
https://www.examples.com/user/username#page1-videos (the "1" in "page1" is the varying element, for the 2nd page it would be "2")
The links that are on the web pages follow this pattern:
https://www.example.com/video/1423061

I have a few questions:

The original code refers to name_list and link_list, I don't need the column containing name_list in the final .csv, all I need is the urls. I tried simply deleting everything involving name_list, but the df end up being empty. How do I correct this?

I want to put all the urls to scrape in a .txt file and have the code iterate through each line in the .txt. How do I do that?


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
i=0
name_list =[]
link_list = []
while(i<=13780):
    print("https://jito.org/members?start={}".format(i))
    res=requests.get("https://jito.org/members?start={}".format(i))
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
    for item in soup.select('.name>a'):
        name_list.append(item.text)
        link_list.append("https://jito.org" + item['href'])
    i=i+20
    print(name_list)
    print(link_list)

df=pd.DataFrame({"Name":name_list,"Link":link_list})
print(df)
df.to_csv('JITO_Directory.csv', index=False)
print('Done')

Each webpage I'm scraping has 40 links, so if I scrape 2 pages, for example https://www.example.com/user/person#page2 and https://www.example.com/user/person3#page7. I want to have a .txt or .csv file with the 80 links scraped from the 2 pages:
https://www.example.com/video/1423061
https://www.example.com/video/1417634
https://www.example.com/video/1417639
etc.


Your question is confusing. In your code you're crawling https://jito.org/ but you mention https://www.example.com/ in the text. Also I don't see any links that contain /video at the target URL. Would you mind please clarifying the question? Thanks.

import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

BASE_URL = "https://jito.org"

i=0

profiles =[]

while True:
    url = BASE_URL + f"/members?start={i}"
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(f"- Status: {response.status_code}.")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")

    links = soup.select('h3.name > a')
    print(f"- Got {len(links)} links.")
    
    # Stop when there are no more profiles.
    if len(links) == 0:
        break

    for link in links:
        profiles.append({
            "name": link.text,
            "url": BASE_URL + link["href"]
        })

    # Go easy on the site.
    time.sleep(3)

    i += 20

df = pd.DataFrame(profiles)
print(df)
df.to_csv('jito-directory.csv', index=False)

Changes that I made to your original code:

Don't hard code number of profiles. Rather keep paginating until there's no more data.
Instead of maintaining two lists for names and links, just build a list of dictionaries.
Pause between requests. This is just good web scraping practice because it reduces your impact on the performance of the target site.

This is what the resulting CSV file looks like:
name,url
Bajrang Lal Bothra,https://jito.org/profile/16447-bajrang-lal-bothra
Sumermal Bhimraj Mehta,https://jito.org/profile/16446-sumermal-bhimraj-mehta
Sukhraj B. Nahar,https://jito.org/profile/16445-sukhraj-b-nahar
Girish Dharampal Jain,https://jito.org/profile/16443-girish-dharampal-jain
Sajjan Lodha,https://jito.org/profile/16444-sajjan-lodha
Nihar Lalit Doshi,https://jito.org/profile/16442-nihar-lalit-doshi
Punyapal Surana,https://jito.org/profile/16441-punyapal-surana
Pratik Jain,https://jito.org/profile/16440-pratik-jain
Mahesh Golechha,https://jito.org/profile/16439-mahesh-golechha
Prasanna Shantilal Mutha,https://jito.org/profile/16438-prasanna-shantilal-mutha
Anil Bohra,https://jito.org/profile/16437-anil-bohra
Vishal Jain,https://jito.org/profile/16436-vishal-jain
Praveen Kumar Jain,https://jito.org/profile/16435-praveen-kumar-jain
Rakesh Kumar Jain,https://jito.org/profile/16434-rakesh-kumar-jain
Rithesh Hirachand Mehta,https://jito.org/profile/16433-rithesh-hirachand-mehta
Sheetal Kumar M (Mehta),https://jito.org/profile/16432-sheetal-kumar-m-mehta
Dineshkumar Champalal Kankulol,https://jito.org/profile/16431-dineshkumar-champalal-kankulol
Kiran Babulal Kumar,https://jito.org/profile/16430-kiran-babulal-kumar
Nemichand Sunil Kumar (Bohra),https://jito.org/profile/16429-nemichand-sunil-kumar-bohra
Kuldeep Mahipal Mehta,https://jito.org/profile/16428-kuldeep-mahipal-mehta

